# A better way to plot dataframe value per category that have a lot of outliers boxplot with python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I have the following boxplot of data value per hour. The x-axis is an hour in 24 hours and y-axis values in log scale. As you can see there is a huge part of data which is outside of the whisker. The black dots outside the whisker are kind of outliers but, they are important and I don't want to remove them. How do I represent them in a plot? or How do I show the variance of values per hour?
Unfortunately, I can not provide the sample data. But the code that I used to generate the plot is something similar as shown below.

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6, 4))
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(211)
df.boxplot(column = 'value', by = 'Hour', ax= ax1)
ax1.set_yscale('log')
```

I appreciate any help [image]

Comment: *How do I represent them in a plot?* They're already represented. I think you're good to go there. *How do I show the variance of values per hour?* Compute the variance for each group and add it to another plot.

Comment: I mean in a better way, to show the variance. I tried to use relative standard deviation in percentage but stacked. The black value on the top of each whisker is too dense and I have got difficulty to make a conclusion out them.

Comment: you could change the marker to a point instead of an open circle. But it real sounds like you want to compute descriptive statistics of the outliers alone, in which case this sounds more like a data preparation problem than a visualization problem.